# What does "Ich han zwei Hölzigi dihei" mean?

Tags: dialect, swiss-german

Asking for a friend, could not figure it out.

Context: It was spoken in Swiss German

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Please [edit] your question to elaborate what you already found and know. Note that we are not a translation service.

Comment: This means "I have two *somethings* at home"; sorry can't image what the substantive is, definitely something a Swabian should be able to decode. Any more context?

Comment: In addition to @guidot `Hölzigi` might mean something along the line of `hölzern`. I am no *Schwabe* myself but I live in the *Schwabenland* and I don't think this is related to *schwäbisch*. They would pronounce `zwei` and `daheim` differently. I think, it might either be related to the Netherlands or retrieved from some olter writings. Googling resulted in some old books where `hölzigi` was used in the context of `wooden`.

Comment: You should take the effort and decorate your question with context. This will decisively increase the probability that somebody can help you with your question. - Für die Kollegen hier: Mir scheint das aus dem alemannischen Bereich zu kommen, Schweiz vielleicht, vielleicht auch Schwarzwald.

Comment: It is probably [Zurich German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zurich_German) or a dialect close to it.

Answer (score 6):

Ohne eine ordentliche Angabe zum Kontext, in dem dieser Satz auftritt, kann man nicht viel damit anfangen. Eine reine Übersetzung ist

> Ich habe zwei hölzerne zuhause / I have two wooden [ones] at home

Man benutze eine Suchmaschine seines Vertrauens und suche nach *hölzigi*. Man findet verschiedene Zitate aus v.a. alemannischen Dialekten wie

> "Grad bim Vorort Augustonemetum isch s Quellhailigtum vo Clermont-Ferrand gsii, wo **hölzigi Götterstatue** gfunde wore sind."

Aus einer dialektalen Reisebeschreibung: "Gleich beim Vorort Augustonemetum ist das Quellheiligtum von Clermont-Ferrand gewesen, wo hölzerne Götterstatuen gefunden worden sind."

> "Der Männerchor Häggenschwil ist seit jeher für seine unterhaltsamen Theaterstücke bekannt. Diesmal unterhält er mit dem Schwank «**Di hölzigi Jungfrau**». Das Stück verspricht Spass und lebt von Wortwitz und Szenenhumor."

Aus dem St. Galler Tagblatt; es geht um ein Theaterstück mit Namen "Die hölzerne Jungfrau"

> **Hölzigi Geiss**

"Hölzerne Ziege" - Titel einer Skulptur des Bildhauers Rene Küng aus dem Jahr 1971. Die Skulptur ist aus Holz und stellt [eine Ziege](http://www.renekueng.ch/index.php?id=444&L=nfbcnoeatfpa) dar (traraa!).